# Calling a Component Via a Prop in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component, react-icons

I am creating a wrapper component for icons that I import using `react-icons`.  Here is an example of how it looks right now:

```
import { FaTwitter as Twitter} from 'react-icons/fa'
import { Icon } from './elements 

<Icon>
 <Twitter />
<Icon>
```

Now, this works just as I want it to -- but I would like to simplify the code.  Ideally, I'd like it to look/work like this:

```
<Icon name='twitter' />
```

Any idea how to do this?

---

**NOTE:** In case it helps, here is current code for my `Icon` component:

```
export const Icon = props => <IconBase {...props} />
```

The `<IconBase>` component is just some styles from `styled-components`.

---

**UPDATE**

I just want to note that the Twitter example is just that -- an example.  I'm looking for a solution that will work no matter what name I pass to the `<Icon>` component.  So, in other words, all of the following (and more) will work:

```
<Icon name="Facebook" />
<Icon name="Search" />
<Icon name="Menu" />
```

Each of these would be equivalent to:

```
<Icon><Facebook /></Icon>
<Icon><Search /></Icon>
<Icon><Menu /></Icon>
```

In other words, no matter what icon I pull in from `react-icons`, it will render properly vis-a-vis the `name` prop.

Comment: You can create an dictionary object which points to the component you want to render as `Icon` children. something like `{twitter: <Twitter />}`

Comment: Is twitter a function?

Comment: @Jesse Twitter is a component.   So `<Icon name="twitter"`/> would be equivalent to `<Icon><Twitter /></Icon>`

Comment: @JohnSnow I'm not following how that would work.  Would you mind showing me a more detailed example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
// definition:
const Icon = (props) => <SomeIconWrapper><props.glyph /></SomeIconWrapper>;
// usage:
<Icon glyph={Twitter} />
```

It is super simple and flexible, no need for any dictionary or so.

Comment: Yes but in the example he is using a `String` as the prop and not a `Component`. That is the requirement. I thought the whole challenge was converting the string to reference the component.

Comment: I would rather use a `String`, but I'm open to using a `Component`.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this would satisfy your condition.

```
const App = () => <Icon name="twitter" />;

const dict = { twitter: <Twitter /> };

const Icon = ({ name }) => <IconBase>{dict[name]}</IconBase>;
```

Comment: Thanks for the example.  For this method to work, though, I'll need to create a new dictionary entry for each and every icon I want to use -- Facebook, Youtube, MenuIcon, Search Icon, etc?  Is there a way to generalize this so that it will automatically work no matter which name I pass in?

Comment: Well you can just pass the Component as the name prop and reference it as `{props.name}` inside of your Icon component. But if your constraint is that you want to use `name="{string}"` then I don't think there would be another way.

Comment: If you want to use a `String` as your prop then you'd have to use the dictionary. If you pass the actual Component, then you don't. You can also use the render prop pattern. `<Icon render={(Component)=> <Component />} />` They are all the same result...

Comment: Thanks -- in the end, I went for this option:  `export const Icon = props => <IconBase><props.name /></IconBase>;`.  Which I render as follows:  `<Icon name={Facebook} />`